# String separated by \n to dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, cat

I have the following string:

```
  "Title\nToday 1,239 €\nYesterday 1,2 €\n17/04/2018 1,2 €\n14/04/2018 1,2 €\n13/04/2018 1,2 €\n12/04/2018 1,2 €\n11/04/2018 1,2 €\n09/04/2018 1,2 €\n08/04/2018 1,2 €\n07/04/2018 1,2 €"
```

But I don´t know if I can get a dataframe from it. I want to get a dataframe with two columns (Date and Price) with my string as follows (don't really need the `Title` name):

```
Date       Price
Today      1,239 €
Yesteday   1,2 €
17/04/2018 1,2 €
14/04/2018 1,2 €
13/04/2018 1,2 €
12/04/2018 1,2 €
11/04/2018 1,2 €
09/04/2018 1,2 €
08/04/2018 1,2 €
07/04/2018 1,2 €
```

This is almost the same that I can get with `cat` function. But I think I can convert it to dataframe.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here a solution with `read.table`:

```
> read.table(text=str, sep=' ', skip=1, col.names=c('Date', 'Price', 'Currency'))
         Date Price Currency
1       Today 1,239        €
2   Yesterday   1,2        €
3  17/04/2018   1,2        €
4  14/04/2018   1,2        €
5  13/04/2018   1,2        €
6  12/04/2018   1,2        €
7  11/04/2018   1,2        €
8  09/04/2018   1,2        €
9  08/04/2018   1,2        €
10 07/04/2018   1,2        €
```

with `str` being your data. Note the argument `skip` is removing the 'Title'.

Comment: If you want two columns (Price and Currency) together, you can summarize with `data.frame(Date=df$Date, Price=paste(df$Price, df$Currency))` with `df` as the data frame from the above command

Comment: simple and elegant - I like it +1 (I ran it myself, instead of "€" I get "<U+0080>" - any idea why?)

Comment: some encoding issue... which OS are you running?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest doing something like this to convert your string `s` into a `data.frame`. The idea is to separate Date, Value and Unit, allowing for easier processing of the data, since you keep units and numeric entries separate.

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(
    unlist(strsplit(sub("Title\n", "", s), "\n")),
    " "))
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Value", "Unit");
df$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(sub(",", ".", df$Value)));
#         Date Value Unit
#1       Today 1.239    €
#2   Yesterday 1.200    €
#3  17/04/2018 1.200    €
#4  14/04/2018 1.200    €
#5  13/04/2018 1.200    €
#6  12/04/2018 1.200    €
#7  11/04/2018 1.200    €
#8  09/04/2018 1.200    €
#9  08/04/2018 1.200    €
#10 07/04/2018 1.200    €
```

Explanation: We split `s` first on `"\n"` and then on white-spaces to separate out `Date`, `Value` and `Unit`. Since your values contain a comma decimal separator ",", we replace "," with "." and convert to `numeric`.

---

You can avoid `sub("Title\n", "", s)` (thanks @PoGibas), making it slighty more compact, by doing:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(unlist(strsplit(s, "\n"))[-1], " "))
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Value", "Unit");
df$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(sub(",", ".", df$Value)));
```

The output is the same as above.

---

### Sample data

```
s <-   "Title\nToday 1,239 €\nYesterday 1,2 €\n17/04/2018 1,2 €\n14/04/2018 1,2 €\n13/04/2018 1,2 €\n12/04/2018 1,2 €\n11/04/2018 1,2 €\n09/04/2018 1,2 €\n08/04/2018 1,2 €\n07/04/2018 1,2 €"
```

Comment: You can use `[-1]` on first `strsplit` output instead of `sub`.

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas; I've made an edit to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a `strsplit` a couple of times, then I build a `matrix` which is converted in to a dataframe (to drop the € sign by taking columns 1 & 2 of the matrix):

```
# Making a short object containing your string
x <- "Title\nToday 1,239 €\nYesterday 1,2 €\n17/04/2018 1,2 €\n14/04/2018 1,2 €\n13/04/2018 1,2 €\n12/04/2018 1,2 €\n11/04/2018 1,2 €\n09/04/2018 1,2 €\n08/04/2018 1,2 €\n07/04/2018 1,2 €"

# Two string splits (first splitting by "\n" and then by " "), and discarding the "title" (by taking [[1]][2:11])
x <- unlist(strsplit(strsplit(x, split = "\n")[[1]][2:11], split = " "))

# Putting it in a data frame (dropping the € symbol)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 3, byrow = T)[,1:2])
```

And the result:

```
> df1
           X1    X2
1       Today 1,239
2   Yesterday   1,2
3  17/04/2018   1,2
4  14/04/2018   1,2
5  13/04/2018   1,2
6  12/04/2018   1,2
7  11/04/2018   1,2
8  09/04/2018   1,2
9  08/04/2018   1,2
10 07/04/2018   1,2
```

---

I'd also add in to sub the "," to "." and have the value as numeric

```
x <- unlist(strsplit(strsplit(x, split = "\n")[[1]][2:11], split = " "))
x <- gsub(",", ".", x)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 3, byrow = T)[,1:2])
df1[,2] <- as.numeric(levels(df1[,2]))[df1[,2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `strsplit` and `dplyr::separate`.

```
prices <- "Title\nToday 1,239 €\nYesterday 1,2 €\n17/04/2018 1,2 €\n14/04/2018 1,2 €\n13/04/2018 1,2 €\n12/04/2018 1,2 €\n11/04/2018 1,2 €\n09/04/2018 1,2 €\n08/04/2018 1,2 €\n07/04/2018 1,2 €"

prices <- data.frame(x = strsplit(prices, "\n", "", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])
prices <- prices %>% separate(x, " ", into = c("Date", "Prices"), extra = "merge") 
prices <- prices[-1,]
prices
#          Date  Prices
# 2       Today 1,239 €
# 3   Yesterday   1,2 €
# 4  17/04/2018   1,2 €
# 5  14/04/2018   1,2 €
# 6  13/04/2018   1,2 €
# 7  12/04/2018   1,2 €
# 8  11/04/2018   1,2 €
# 9  09/04/2018   1,2 €
# 10 08/04/2018   1,2 €
# 11 07/04/2018   1,2 €
```